# how to do a sum weighted in a datatable?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a data table like this :

```
Date     Qty    Price 
----------------------
12/07    10      2
12/09    20      3
12/05    12      2
12/05    8       6
8/9      85      56
```

If we have 2 rows with the same date, i want to calculate the weighted price of both column. So the datable becomes :

```
Date     Qty         Price 
----------------------------
12/07    10          2
12/09    20          3
12/05    20 (12+8)   3.6 (12*2 + 8*6)/(12+8)
8/9      85          56
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Date, SUM(Qty), SUM(QtyPrice)/SUM(Qty)
FROM
(
  SELECT Date, Qty, Qty * Price AS QtyPrice
  FROM Table
)
GROUP BY Date
```

Should do it

In C#:

```
var groups = table.AsEnumerable().
                   GroupBy(row => row.Field<DateTime>("Date")).
                   Select(group => new 
                   { 
                     Date = group.Key, 
                     Quantity = group.Sum(item => item.Qty),
                     Price = group.Sum(item => item.Qty * item.Price)
                   });
```

Comment: I forget to tell that i am coding in c#

Comment: @francopshenri I've updated my answer accordingly (you'll need .net >= 3.5 to use linq to dataset)

Comment: Actually , what I want to do is to calculate the weighted average price if one have 2 rows with the same date in my case : rows corresponding to the date 12/05